# Using MFMessageComposeViewController to Send to an Array of Numbers Individually

Tags: ios, sms, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

Currently I am trying to send sms from a users phone through an app.
The idea is that the user selects the recipients of the message and then one by one the message is sent to each recipient.
Currently this is how I am doing it after a button is clicked this happens

```
if (self.abNumbersSelected.count > 0){
                for(NSString *phoneNumber in self.abNumbersSelected)
                {
                    if(self.currentController)
                        [self.currentController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{[self sendInviteMessage:phoneNumber];}
                         ];
                    else
                        [self sendInviteMessage:phoneNumber];// message that invites selected message
                }
            }
```

`abNumbersSelected` is an array of numbers that the user has picked the `sendInviteMessage` is here:

```
- (void)sendInviteMessage:(NSString*)invitingNumber
{
    //Invites the numbers using sms
    //First checks if it duplicates it
    if ([self checkDuplicate:invitingNumber]) {
        UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Invalid Phone Number" message:@"The phone number you entered is not valid." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
        self.phoneField.text = @"";
    }
    //if not a duplicate then it sends the message
    else {
        if (SharedSessionManager.authToken) {
            NSString* currentUserName = @"";
            if (SharedSessionManager.currentUser.firstName && SharedSessionManager.currentUser.lastName) {
                currentUserName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", SharedSessionManager.currentUser.firstName, SharedSessionManager.currentUser.lastName];
            }
            else if (SharedSessionManager.currentUser.firstName) {
                currentUserName = SharedSessionManager.currentUser.firstName;
            }
            if (!customLoadingView.isLoading)
                [customLoadingView beginLoading];
            MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
            if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
            {
                NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ invited you to join Friendli - a mobile, location based social network. Join now at friendli.co",currentUserName];
                controller.body = message;
                controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:invitingNumber, nil];
                controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
                controller.disableUserAttachments;
                controller.title = @"Invite Friend";
                self.currentController = controller;
                [self presentModalViewController:self.currentController animated:YES];
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Currently no message shows up to be sent. 
Also here is the `messageComposeViewController:` method

```
- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult) result
{
    switch (result) {
        case MessageComposeResultCancelled:
            break;

        case MessageComposeResultFailed:
        {
            UIAlertView *warningAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to send SMS!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [warningAlert show];
            break;
        }

        case MessageComposeResultSent:
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

In the log this is what is said when 2 recipients are picked and the button to trigger the MFMessageComposeViewController to be created is clicked by the user

2015-06-05 13:29:10:521 Friendli[241:807] [self.abNumbersSelected count]: 2

2015-06-05 13:29:11:638 Friendli[241:807] Reading auth token from keychain. (friendli.116.authtoken)

2015-06-05 13:29:11:643 Friendli[241:807] Reading auth token from keychain. (friendli.116.authtoken)

2015-06-05 13:29:12.869 Friendli[241:10525] Remote compose controller timed out (NO)!

Comment: I realized that I have 2 dismiss statements and took out the first one so the code is now `for(NSString *phoneNumber in self.abNumbersSelected)
                {
                    [self sendInviteMessage:phoneNumber];// message that invites selected message
                }`

Comment: and this comes in the debugger when I try to send messages to 2 people: 2015-06-05 23:31:41.268 Friendli[1336:159133] Attempt to present <MFMessageComposeViewController: 0x171bea00> on <InviteFriendsViewController: 0x16ee2180> which is waiting for a delayed presention of <MFMessageComposeViewController: 0x17954a00> to complete

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult) result
{
    switch (result) {
        case MessageComposeResultCancelled:
            break;

        case MessageComposeResultFailed:
        {
            UIAlertView *warningAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to send SMS!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [warningAlert show];
            break;
        }

        case MessageComposeResultSent:
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        if (self.abNumbersSelected.count > 0 && self.multipleRecipients) {
            [self sendInviteMessage:[self.abNumbersSelected objectAtIndex:0]];
        }
    }];
}
```

In the didFinish method for the MFMessageComposeController in the dismiss statement using the if statement in the block of code the code will continue to create more MFMessageComposeViewControllers till it is done.